# MySQL connecting with wrong username and password

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to the site. My problem is that I'm trying to connect to MySQL and it connects every time even with rubbish values. This is my code:

```
<?php

$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","hhfhhfdj","hyugyhoij");
if(!connect) {
echo "We are currently encountering some problems, kindly check back later";
} else {
echo "connected successfully";
}

?>
```

Also, isn't there a better way to insert code on here without having to indent it one by one? What if I had 20 lines of code?

Comment: Clearly you're using the wrong password.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you about the PHP code (Rails dev). However, as for the changing lines into code, highlight the ones you want to show as code and press command K.

Comment: Thanks guys but that was the point of the question: it connects even if i put the wrong password. Thanks Njay for the tip.

Comment: I think your if condition is wrong.Try using:
`if ($connect->connect_error)`

Comment: [As impressive as it is `connect` alone will yield true hence `!connect` will always go to the else as it is true.](https://eval.in/192625) However what you're looking for is `if ($connect->connect_error)` as you have no constant called `connect` and your variable starts with `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who commented. I spotted my mistake! i had written if(!connect) without the dollar sign in front of "connect" lol

Answer (score 0):

I think your if condition is wrong.

mysqli_connect will always return an object (see [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)) so `if(!connect)` will always be false (because for any non-null object, `if(object)` is always true)

Try using `if ($connect->connect_error)` instead

Answer (score 0):

You might miss the syntax of using **mysqli_connect**, then correct syntax of **mysqli_connect** is

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'dbUser', 'dbPassword', 'dbName')
```

Comment: database name is an optional field and you have `mysqli_select_db` in case you don't specify one or need to switch.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

check with your username and password.

```
<?php

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 

if($connect){
   echo "connected..";
}
?>
```